# Flagging as duplicate to answer wikis or other lengthy historical questions

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, community-wiki

How should duplicates to answer wikis or other comprehensive questions be flagged? Are they still duplicates, what is the appropriate flag or action?

I've flagged [How do I create my own Git branch to work on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720268/how-do-i-create-my-own-git-branch-to-work-on) as a duplicate to [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide), but that question and answer is a lengthy guide. This one is a duplicate, but much more specific.

Comment: If the question obviously was poorly researched and the OP doesn't seem to put any efforts in it, I personally have no scruples to mark it with a broad dupe. That's more or less an educational lesson for the OP.

Comment: Not sure if it was poor research by OP, or just poor wording of their question. I would hope flagging as dupe is a direct link to a more clearly worded question usually (or at least first instance of the question). But in this instance the most direct duplicate link is from the new question to an old answer, and not another question.

Comment: related: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773)

Comment: Is "[I don't understand these git command's meaning, who can explain then to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858249/i-dont-understand-these-git-commands-meaning-who-can-explain-then-to-me)" an example of what you meant? I really want that one gone.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that one mixes in bad grammar and spelling from a non-native english speaker. I think my original one didn't know the terms used when working with the tool, so it would only miss on terminology.